# Iterate over multiple lists and show them in list tiles in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
class A {
  String name;
  String pic;
}
    
class B {
  String name;
  String pic;
}
    
class C{
  String name;
  String pic;
}
        
class D {
  List<A> as;
  List<B> bs;
  List<C> cs;
}
    
    
D callApi() async{
  final response = repo.getData();
  D d = response.data;
  return d;
}
```

I want to put the as, bs and cs in separate  `ListTiles`. (first all the as list tiles than all the bs etc...) What's the best way to iterate over the lists in `d` and serve them up as `ListTiles`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Dart 2.3` there is spread operator (`...`), so you can use it to iterate through your lists. The best option is to create a template class which contains `name` and `pic` fields and a method to create `ListTile`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class ABC {
  final String name;
  final String pic;

  ABC(this.name, this.pic);

  ListTile createListTile() => ListTile(
        title: Text(name),
        // TODO: configure as you need
      );
}

class A extends ABC {
  A(String name, String pic) : super(name, pic);
}

class B extends ABC {
  B(String name, String pic) : super(name, pic);
}

class C extends ABC {
  C(String name, String pic) : super(name, pic);
}

class D {
  List<A> as;
  List<B> bs;
  List<C> cs;
}

Future<D> callApi() async {
  final response = repo.getData();
  D d = response.data;
  return d;
}

Future<void> main() async {
  final d = await callApi();
  final listTiles = <ListTile>[
    for (var as in d.as) ...{
      as.createListTile(),
    },
    for (var bs in d.bs) ...{
      bs.createListTile(),
    },
    for (var cs in d.bs) ...{
      cs.createListTile(),
    },
  ];

  //TODO: do something with `listTiles`
}
```

You can go even to more elegant solution and use `extension` on `List<ABC>` (available since `Dart 2.7`). Then, `ABC` class should look like

```dart
abstract class ABC {
  final String name;
  final String pic;

  ABC(this.name, this.pic);
}
```

Extension:

```dart
extension ListABC on List<ABC> {
  List<ListTile> convertToListTiles() {
    var items = <ListTile>[];
    for (var item in this) {
      items.add(ListTile(
        title: Text(item.name),
        // TODO: configure as you need
      ));
    }

    return items;
  }
}
```

And you can use it like that:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  final d = await callApi();
  final listTiles = <ListTile>[
    ...d.as.convertToListTiles(),
    ...d.bs.convertToListTiles(),
    ...d.cs.convertToListTiles(),
  ];

  //TODO: do something with `listTiles`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create one `List` and then use that in a `ListView.builder`.

```
final List<dynamic> items = [...d.as,...d.bs,...d.cs];
```

and

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(items[index].name),
    );
  },
);
```

However, I would suggest defining a common interface and letting the classes implement that interface. That way you can have type safety instead of having to use `dynamic`